# Puppeteer: Unable to load full html content?

Tags: angularjs, puppeteer

I am trying to fetch full HTML page content of a single page web application (AngularJS) using **puppeteer**. But I got only HTML content of header and footer. This code working fine on my local machine but not working on **AMI server**.

```
//function for timeout

async function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
// function to crawl a html page using a url 
async function crawler(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url); //fetch url
  await timeout(5000); // wait for 5 second to load full page
  const html = await page.evaluate(() => document.documentElement.outerHTML);
  await browser.close();
  return html;
}
```

Also tried `waitFor` and `networkidle2` but didn't get proper HTML in result.

Comment: Probably your server IP is banned by the target site. Happens with AWS IP ranges all the time.

Comment: Puppeteer and website Code is deployed on same server and accessing using http://127.0.0.1.

Comment: Are you sure the site's working correctly then on AMI?

Comment: Yes, Its working fine. I can access it through public and private IP.

Comment: Does it work well via 127.0.0.1 as well? What happens if you give puppeteer on the server the public IP of the server?

Comment: Its running using node server on 8888 port and using public and private IP i can access it. But it just return static html, I need full rendered html(with dynamic part).

Comment: Again — do you give puppeteer the same address nad port that **definitely** works in the browser? I just guess that puppeteer receives HTML but can't get other resources for the page.

Comment: Now resolved, Its because chrome unable to access apis servers. Thank you Vaviloff

Comment: Please post an answer to the issue then (or... maybe delete the question?) so it is useful for other readers in the future.

Comment: It's cleaner to use `page.waitFor(5000);` over `await timeout(5000);`